# Question about complex number infinite tetrations

Tags: complex-numbers, lambert-w, tetration

I was researching infinite tetrations recently and thought of a super interesting, although admittedly pointless, math question regarding it. I was wondering if anyone can help me solve it.

Say we have i^i, can you take an infinite tetration of that? And more generally, can you take the infinite tetration of any complex number (a+bi)^(a+bi)? It's kinda random, but it seems pretty neat.

Just an interesting thought that I couldn't really figure out.

Thanks

Edit: Someone pointed out that "tetration" is a bit vague. What I mean is repeated exponentiation, so like the infinite tetration of x is x^x^x^x^x... so on. So I'm asking about (i^i)^(i^i)^(i^i)^(i^i)...

Comment: Despite its informal use, the word "tetration" does not have a well-defined meaning in mathematics. In order for readers to know what you are asking, it would be best if you expressed your question in clear mathematical language.

Comment: Sorry to deceive you : it is an exaggeration to say "super interesting math question". One sees these last years many questions about "Tetration", but alas, it is an operation that has never been useful in "real mathematics", either on the theoretical or on the applied side of mathematics.

Comment: Do you already have a good understanding of complex exponentiation as in $i^i$? Which value of $i^i$ do you have in mind? If the real one, is it in the domain where the limit for the infinite power tower exists? etc. Basically, what math/background research have you already done, and where did you get stuck/unsure?